# Passing functions to ReactNative Library ActionButton

Tags: react-native

**Background**

I am using [xotahal/react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/blob/master/src/ActionButton/ActionButton.react.js) material design in my `React-Native` application. I have implemented the `ActionButton` with multiple buttons in it. I can not find anywhere in the docs that is explains how to use this. I was able to find the component in the git repo and managed getting the buttons to render but I can't get them to fire of `onClick()`.

**Example**

The buttons appear when the main blue button is clicked.

[image]

**Question**

What is the proper way to pass functions to these buttons, or where in the documentation is this explained?

**Code**

```
<ActionButton
    actions={[ 
        { icon: 'note-add', label: 'Add', onPress: () => this.toggleSearch() },
        { icon: 'save', label: 'Save', onPress: () => this.handleOnSave() },]}
```

/>

```
toggleSearch() {
        console.log('################## HEY SEARCH WORKS ##########################');

    }
```

Problem with this is that no functions are fired when I click the button.

I would be grateful if someone knows where this is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code please?

Comment: Sure, I am just trying to console.log() something to get the OnClick to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionButton` `actions` prop expects an object with the shape of `{icon, label, name}`. If you want to handle `onPress` you need to define it as a prop to the component and not to the actions object.

**Example**

```
<ActionButton
    actions={[ 
        { icon: 'note-add', label: 'Add' },
        { icon: 'save', label: 'Save'}]}
    onPress={(text) => this.onPress(text)}
/>

// ...

onPress(text) {
  switch(text) {
    case:
      // do something on this case
      break;
    case:
      // do another thing on this case
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya I just figured it out, thanks! Is this written somewhere in the docs?

Comment: I didn't check docs. I just see it in the page you added on your question where the props defined.

Comment: omg... " Called when button is long pressed. Text is passed as param " I missed that. Thanks bro have a good day.

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help. Have a good day yourself too